# pyparsing optimize skip rest of line

Tags: python, pyparsing

We use `to_eol = SkipTo(lineEnd(), include=True)` in some of our parsers to eat the rest of the line. Since `SkipTo` re-evaluates the inner parser at every position, I was trying to simplify the work using `Regex`.

As `lineEnd` only recognizes `\n`, I thought that `Regex('[^\\n]*\\n')` should work.

It doesn't, and I can't quite figure out why. I've tried a bunch of variants - adding multiline regex mode, accepting more than one newline in a row, etc., but none of them have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be tripping over pyparsing's default whitespace skipping and regex multiline. Pyparsing defines a helper `restOfLine` as `Regex(r".*").leaveWhitespace().setName("rest of line")`. Note that this might match an empty string, so `OneOrMore(restOfLine)` will loop forever.